# slow jquery plugins with ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I'm using Jquery plugins with literal and repeater control in vb.net. Unfortunately the performance of the plugin is very slow and I've narrowed it down to the following code:(I used literal in html page)

```
Sub GetAllItems()
Dim dt As DataTable = altharaaonline.DXNitems.GetAllDXNitems()
Dim Lt_Body As String = ""
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Lt_Body += "<li class=""item mix_row""><div class=""outer box""> <a href=""#"" class=""product-image""><img src=""" & dt.Rows(i).Item("ImgUrl").ToString & """ alt=""" & dt.Rows(i).Item("ProductNameEnglish").ToString & """ width=""117px"" height=""165px"" /></a><div class=""ic_caption""><h2 class=""product-name""><a href=""Item.aspx?id=" & dt.Rows(i).Item("Id").ToString & """ title=""" & dt.Rows(i).Item("ProductNameEnglish").ToString & """ </a></h2><div class=""actions""><button style=""display:none;"" type=""button"" title=""Add to Cart"" class=""button btn-cart""> <span> <span>Add to Cart</span> </span> </button><a rel=""example_group"" href=""./images/zoom1.jpg"" class=""fancybox quickllook"" id=""fancybox170"">Quick look</a><div class=""price-box""> <span class=""regular-price""> <span class=""price"">" & dt.Rows(i).Item("SellingPrice").ToString & "</span> </span> </div></div></div></div></li>"
Next
Literal1.Text = Lt_Body

End Sub
```

While the Jquery code was :

```
typeof YUI!="undefined"&&(YUI._YUI=YUI);var YUI=function(){var a=0,b=this,c=arguments,d=c.length,e=function(a,b){return a&&a.hasOwnProperty&&a instanceof b},f=typeof YUI_config!="undefined"&&YUI_config;e(b,YUI)?(b._init(),YUI.GlobalConfig&&b.applyConfig(YUI.GlobalConfig),f&&b.applyConfig(f),d||b._setup()):b=new YUI;if(d){for(;a<d;a++)b.applyConfig(c[a]);b._setup()}return b.instanceOf=e,b};(function(){var a,b,c="3.4.1",d=".",e="http://yui.yahooapis.com/",f="yui3-js-enabled",g=function(){},h=Array.prototype.slice,i={"io.xdrReady":1,"io.xdrResponse":1,"SWF.eventHandler":1},j=typeof window!="undefined",k=j?window:null,l=j?k.document:null,m=l&&l.documentElement,n=m&&m.className,o={},p=(new Date).getTime(),q=function(a,b,c,d){a&&a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener(b,c,d):a&&a.attachEvent&&a.attachEvent("on"+b,c)},r=function(a,b,c,d){if(a&&a.removeEventListener)try{a.removeEventListener(b,c,d)}catch(e){}else a&&a.detachEvent&&a.detachEvent("on"+b,c)},s=function(){YUI.Env.windowLoaded=!0,YUI.Env.DOMReady=!0,j&&r(window,"load",s)},t=function(a,b){var c=a.Env._loader;return c?(c.ignoreRegistered=!1,c.onEnd=null,c.data=null,c.required=[],c.loadType=null):(c=new a.Loader(a.config),a.Env._loader=c),YUI.Env.core=a.Array.dedupe([].concat(YUI.Env.core,["loader-base","loader-rollup","loader-yui3"])),c},u=function(a,b){for(var c in b)b.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(a[c]=b[c])},v={success:!0};m&&n.indexOf(f)==-1&&(n&&(n+=" "),n+=f,m.className=n),c.indexOf("@")>-1&&(c="3.3.0"),a={applyConfig:function(a){a=a||g;var b,c,d=this.config,e=d.modules,f=d.groups,h=d.rls,i=this.Env._loader;for(c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(b=a[c],e&&c=="modules"?u(e,b):f&&c=="groups"?u(f,b):h&&c=="rls"?u(h,b):c=="win"?(d[c]=b.contentWindow||b,d.doc=d[c].document):c!="_yuid"&&(d[c]=b));i&&i._config(a)},_config:function(a){this.applyConfig(a)},_init:function(){var a,b=this,d=YUI.Env,f=b.Env,g;b.version=c;if(!f){b.Env={core:["get","features","intl-base","yui-log","yui-later","loader-base","loader-rollup","loader-yui3"],mods:{},versions:{},base:e,cdn:e+c+"/build/",_idx:0,_used:{},_attached:{},_missed:[],_yidx:0,_uidx:0,_guidp:"y",_loaded:{},_BASE_RE:/(?:\?(?:[^&]*&)*([^&]*))?\b(simpleyui|yui(?:-\w+)?)\/\2(?:-(min|debug))?\.js/,parseBasePath:function(a,b){var c=a.match(b),d,e;return c&&(d=RegExp.leftContext||a.slice(0,a.indexOf(c[0])),e=c[3],c[1]&&(d+="?"+c[1]),d={filter:e,path:d}),d},getBase:d&&d.getBase||function(c){var d=l&&l.getElementsByTagName("script")||[],e=f.cdn,g,h,i,j;for(h=0,i=d.length;h<i;++h){j=d[h].src;if(j){g=b.Env.parseBasePath(j,c);if(g){a=g.filter,e=g.path;break}}}return e}},f=b.Env,f._loaded[c]={};if(d&&b!==YUI)f._yidx=++d._yidx,f._guidp=("yui_"+c+"_"+f._yidx+"_"+p).replace(/\./g,"_");else if(YUI._YUI){d=YUI._YUI.Env,f._yidx+=d._yidx,f._uidx+=d._uidx;for(g in d)g in f||(f[g]=d[g]);delete YUI._YUI}b.id=b.stamp(b),o[b.id]=b}b.constructor=YUI,b.config=b.config||{win:k,doc:l,debug:!0,useBrowserConsole:!0,throwFail:!0,bootstrap:!0,cacheUse:!0,fetchCSS:!0,use_rls:!1,rls_timeout:2e3},YUI.Env.rls_disabled&&(b.config.use_rls=!1),b.config.lang=b.config.lang||"en-US",b.config.base=YUI.config.base||b.Env.getBase(b.Env._BASE_RE);if(!a||!"mindebug".indexOf(a))a="min";a=a?"-"+a:a,b.config.loaderPath=YUI.config.loaderPath||"loader/loader"+a+".js"},_setup:function(a){var b,c=this,d=[],e=YUI.Env.mods,f=c.config.core||[].concat(YUI.Env.core);for(b=0;b<f.length;b++)e[f[b]]&&d.push(f[b]);c._attach(["yui-base"]),c._attach(d),c.Loader&&t(c)},applyTo:function(a,b,c){if(b in i){var d=o[a],e,f,g;if(d){e=b.split("."),f=d;for(g=0;g<e.length;g=g+1)f=f[e[g]],f||this.log("applyTo not found: "+b,"warn","yui");return f.apply(d,c)}return null}return this.log(b+": applyTo not allowed","warn","yui"),null},add:function(a,b,c,d){d=d||{};var e=YUI.Env,f={name:a,fn:b,version:c,details:d},g,h,i=e.versions;e.mods[a]=f,i[c]=i[c]||{},i[c][a]=f;for(h in o)o.hasOwnProperty(h)&&(g=o[h].Env._loader,g&&(g.moduleInfo[a]||g.addModule(d,a)));return this},_attach:function(a,b){var c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j=YUI.Env.mods,k=YUI.Env.aliases,l=this,m,n=l.Env._loader,o=l.Env._attached,p=a.length,n,q=[];for(c=0;c<p;c++)d=a[c],e=j[d],q.push(d),n&&n.conditions[d]&&l.Object.each(n.conditions[d],function(a){var b=a&&(a.ua&&l.UA[a.ua]||a.test&&a.test(l));b&&q.push(a.name)});a=q,p=a.length;for(c=0;c<p;c++)if(!o[a[c]]){d=a[c],e=j[d];if(k&&k[d]){l._attach(k[d]);continue}if(!e)n&&n.moduleInfo[d]&&(e=n.moduleInfo[d],b=!0),b||d.indexOf("skin-")===-1&&d.indexOf("css")===-1&&(l.Env._missed.push(d),l.Env._missed=l.Array.dedupe(l.Env._missed),l.message("NOT loaded: "+d,"warn","yui"));else{o[d]=!0;for(m=0;m<l.Env._missed.length;m++)l.Env._missed[m]===d&&(l.message("Found: "+d+" (was reported as missing earlier)","warn","yui"),l.Env._missed.splice(m,1));f=e.details,g=f.requires,h=f.use,i=f.after;if(g)for(m=0;m<g.length;m++)if(!o[g[m]]){if(!l._attach(g))return!1;break}if(i)for(m=0;m<i.length;m++)if(!o[i[m]]){if(!l._attach(i,!0))return!1;break}if(e.fn)try{e.fn(l,d)}catch(r){return l.error("Attach error: "+d,r,d),!1}if(h)for(m=0;m<h.length;m++)if(!o[h[m]]){if(!l._attach(h))return!1;break}}}return!0},use:function(){var a=h.call(arguments,0),b=a[a.length-1],c=this,d=0,e,f=c.Env,g=!0;c.Lang.isFunction(b)?a.pop():b=null,c.Lang.isArray(a[0])&&(a=a[0]);if(c.config.cacheUse){while(e=a[d++])if(!f._attached[e]){g=!1;break}if(g)return!a.length,c._notify(b,v,a),c}return c._loading?(c._useQueue=c._useQueue||new c.Queue,c._useQueue.add([a,b])):c._use(a,function(c,d){c._notify(b,d,a)}),c},_notify:function(a,b,c){if(!b.success&&this.config.loadErrorFn)this.config.loadErrorFn.call(this,this,a,b,c);else if(a)try{a(this,b)}catch(d){this.error("use callback error",d,c)}},_use:function(a,b){this.Array||this._attach(["yui-base"]);var d,e,f,g,h=this,i=YUI.Env,j=i.mods,k=h.Env,l=k._used,m=i._loaderQueue,n=a[0],o=h.Array,p=h.config,q=p.bootstrap,r=[],s=[],u=!0,v=p.fetchCSS,w=function(a,b){if(!a.length)return;o.each(a,function(a){b||s.push(a);if(l[a])return;var d=j[a],e,f;d?(l[a]=!0,e=d.details.requires,f=d.details.use):i._loaded[c][a]?l[a]=!0:r.push(a),e&&e.length&&w(e),f&&f.length&&w(f,1)})},x=function(c){var d=c||{success:!0,msg:"not dynamic"},e,f,g=!0,i=d.data;h._loading=!1,i&&(f=r,r=[],s=[],w(i),e=r.length,e&&r.sort().join()==f.sort().join()&&(e=!1)),e&&i?(h._loading=!1,h._use(a,function(){h._attach(i)&&h._notify(b,d,i)})):(i&&(g=h._attach(i)),g&&h._notify(b,d,a)),h._useQueue&&h._useQueue.size()&&!h._loading&&h._use.apply(h,h._useQueue.next())};return n==="*"?(u=h._attach(h.Object.keys(j)),u&&x(),h):(q&&h.Loader&&a.length&&(e=t(h),e.require(a),e.ignoreRegistered=!0,e.calculate(null,v?null:"js"),a=e.sorted),w(a),d=r.length,d&&(r=h.Object.keys(o.hash(r)),d=r.length,h.log("Modules missing: "+r+", "+r.length,"info","yui")),q&&d&&h.Loader?(h._loading=!0,e=t(h),e.onEnd=x,e.context=h,e.data=a,e.ignoreRegistered=!1,e.require(a),e.insert(null,v?null:"js")):d&&h.config.use_rls&&!YUI.Env.rls_enabled?(i._rls_queue=i._rls_queue||new h.Queue,g=function(a,b){var c=function(b){x(b),a.rls_advance()},d=a._rls(b);d?(a.rls_oncomplete(function(a){c(a)}),a.Get.script(d,{data:b,timeout:a.config.rls_timeout,onFailure:a.rls_handleFailure,onTimeout:a.rls_handleTimeout})):c({success:!0,data:b})},i._rls_queue.add(function(){i._rls_in_progress=!0,h.rls_callback=b,h.rls_locals(h,a,g)}),!i._rls_in_progress&&i._rls_queue.size()&&i._rls_queue.next()()):q&&d&&h.Get&&!k.bootstrapped?(h._loading=!0,f=function(){h._loading=!1,m.running=!1,k.bootstrapped=!0,i._bootstrapping=!1,h._attach(["loader"])&&h._use(a,b)},i._bootstrapping?(h.log("Waiting for loader","info","yui"),m.add(f)):(i._bootstrapping=!0,h.log("Fetching loader: "+p.base+p.loaderPath,"info","yui"),h.Get.script(p.base+p.loaderPath,{onEnd:f}))):(u=h._attach(a),u&&x()),h)},namespace:function(){var a=arguments,b=this,c=0,e,f,g;for(;c<a.length;c++){g=a[c];if(g.indexOf(d)){f=g.split(d);for(e=f[0]=="YAHOO"?1:0;e<f.length;e++)b[f[e]]=b[f[e]]||{},b=b[f[e]]}else b[g]=b[g]||{}}return b},log:g,message:g,dump:function(a){return""+a},error:function(a,b,c){var d=this,e;d.config.errorFn&&(e=d.config.errorFn.apply(d,arguments));if(d.config.throwFail&&!e)throw b||new Error(a);return d.message(a,"error"),d},guid:function(a){var b=this.Env._guidp+"_"+ ++this.Env._uidx;return a?a+b:b},stamp:function(a,b){var c;if(!a)return a;a.uniqueID&&a.nodeType&&a.nodeType!==9?c=a.uniqueID:c=typeof a=="string"?a:a._yuid;if(!c){c=this.guid();if(!b)try{a._yuid=c}catch(d){c=null}}return c},destroy:function(){var a=this;a.Event&&a.Event._unload(),delete o[a.id],delete a.Env,delete a.config}},YUI.prototype=a;for(b in a)a.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(YUI[b]=a[b]);YUI._init(),j?q(window,"load",s):s(),YUI.Env.add=q,YUI.Env.remove=r,typeof exports=="object"&&(exports.YUI=YUI)})(),YUI.add("yui-base",function(a){function m(a,b,c){var d,e;b||(b=0);if(c||m.test(a))try{return k.slice.call(a,b)}catch(f){e=[];for(d=a.length;b<d;++b)e.push(a[b]);return e}return[a]}function n(){this._init(),this.add.apply(this,arguments)}var b=a.Lang||(a.Lang={}),c=String.prototype,d=Object.prototype.toString,e={"undefined":"undefined",number:"number","boolean":"boolean",string:"string","[object Function]":"function","[object RegExp]":"regexp","[object Array]":"array","[object Date]":"date","[object Error]":"error"},f=/\{\s*([^|}]+?)\s*(?:\|([^}]*))?\s*\}/g,g=/^\s+|\s+$/g,h=a.config.win,i=h&&(!!h.MooTools||!!h.Prototype);b.isArray=!i&&Array.isArray||function(a){return b.type(a)==="array"},b.isBoolean=function(a){return typeof a=="boolean"},b.isFunction=function(a){return b.type(a)==="function"},b.isDate=function(a){return b.type(a)==="date"&&a.toString()!=="Invalid Date"&&!isNaN(a)},b.isNull=function(a){return a===null},b.isNumber=function(a){return typeof a=="number"&&isFinite(a)},b.isObject=function(a,c){var d=typeof a;return a&&(d==="object"||!c&&(d==="function"||b.isFunction(a)))||!1},b.isString=function(a){return typeof a=="string"},b.isUndefined=function(a){return typeof a=="undefined"},b.trim=c.trim?function(a){return a&&a.trim?a.trim():a}:function(a){try{return a.replace(g,"")}catch(b){return a}},b.trimLeft=c.trimLeft?function(a){return a.trimLeft()}:function(a){return a.replace(/^\s+/,"")},b.trimRight=c.trimRight?function(a){return a.trimRight()}:function(a){return a.replace(/\s+$/,"")},b.isValue=function(a){var c=b.type(a);switch(c){case"number":return isFinite(a);case"null":case"undefined":return!1;default:return!!c}},b.type=function(a){return e[typeof a]||e[d.call(a)]||(a?"object":"null")},b.sub=function(a,c){return a.replace?a.replace(f,function(a,d){return b.isUndefined(c[d])?a:c[d]}):a},b.now=Date.now||function(){return(new Date).getTime()};var j=a.Lang,k=Array.prototype,l=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;a.Array=m,m.dedupe=function(a){var b={},c=[],d,e,f;for(d=0,f=a.length;d<f;++d)e=a[d],l.call(b,e)||(b[e]=1,c.push(e));return c},m.each=m.forEach=k.forEach?function(b,c,d){return k.forEach.call(b||[],c,d||a),a}:function(b,c,d){for(var e=0,f=b&&b.length||0;e<f;++e)e in b&&c.call(d||a,b[e],e,b);return a},m.hash=function(a,b){var c={},d=b&&b.length||0,e,f;for(e=0,f=a.length;e<f;++e)e in a&&(c[a[e]]=d>e&&e in b?b[e]:!0);return c},m.indexOf=k.indexOf?function(a,b){return k.indexOf.call(a,b)}:function(a,b){for(var c=0,d=a.length;c<d;++c)if(c in a&&a[c]===b)return c;return-1},m.numericSort=function(a,b){return a-b},m.some=k.some?function(a,b,c){return k.some.call(a,b,c)}:function(a,b,c){for(var d=0,e=a.length;d<e;++
```

sample of what am doing can be viewed in "New Products" section in this page. http://www.palmmart.net/default.aspx

I used repeater also and its the same slowness.

When I open it in html without IIS it works very smoothly as shown here: http://palmmart.net/main.html

Comment: Do you have any jQuery code to post? All I see is YUI

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by slow?  Is it the display of the items in the browser or the execution of the for loop or something else entirely?

Comment: posting minified code will not get you helped on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, not only are you not using jQuery (you're using YUI), but it doesn't look like the front end is your problem. My guess is that concatenating a bunch of long strings on the server is slowing your site down considerably.

Try using a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim dt As DataTable = altharaaonline.DXNitems.GetAllDXNitems()
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    sb.Append("huge long string")
Next

Literal1.Text = sb.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted is not jQuery, it is YUI.

YUI is another Javascript library, which does a lot of the same kind of things as jQuery. The JS code you've posted is the source code for the entire YUI library.

Running both YUI and jQuery on your site is fine, but entirely un-necessary, and is likely to be slow.

On top of that, when I loaded your page, I also see you've included the Prototype library. This is *another* library which does virtually the same thing as jQuery. Again, there's no point having multiple libraries in your site that are doing the same thing (and potentially conflicting with each other).

However, having said all that, the real performance problem on your site isn't the Javascript at all. It's the large number of massive images you're serving. Open your page in a browser with a decent developer toolkit (eg Chrome Dev Tools or Firefox's Firebug), and look at the page load chart -- you'll see that some of your images are taking five, ten or even twenty seconds to download. And some of them are over a meg in size. It's no wonder things are running so slowly.

This is a large part of your problem. Deal with that, and things will be much improved.

You'll also want to get rid of the multiple libraries - probably stick with jQuery, but get rid of the others.

There are other problems with your code too, but I'll leave those to a separate question, or I could be here all night typing this answer.